# sbt runs IMain and play makes errors

Tags: scala, playframework-2.2

I've build a litte object, which can interpret scala code on the fly and catches a value out of it.

```
object Interpreter {
  import scala.tools.nsc._
  import scala.tools.nsc.interpreter._

  class Dummy

  val settings = new Settings
  settings.usejavacp.value = false
  settings.embeddedDefaults[Dummy]  // to make imain useable with sbt.

  val imain = new IMain(settings)

  def run(code: String, returnId: String) = {
    this.imain.beQuietDuring{
      this.imain.interpret(code)
    }
    val ret = this.imain.valueOfTerm(returnId)
    this.imain.reset()
    ret
  }
}

object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    println(Interpreter.run("val x = 1", "x"))
  }
}
```

In a pure `sbt` environment or called by the `scala` interpreter this code works fine! But if I run this in a simple `play` (version 2.2.2) application, it gets a null pointer at `val ret = this.imain.valueOfTerm(returnId)`.

**`play` uses also a *modified* sbt, therefor it should probably work. What does `play` do that this code doesn't work anymore? Any ideas how to get this code to work in `play`?**

### Note

That's the used `build.sbt`:

```
name := "Test"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.3"

libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang" % "scala-compiler" % scalaVersion.value
```

Alternatively I tried this implementation, but it doesen't solve the problem either:

```
object Interpreter2 {
  import scala.tools.nsc._
  import scala.tools.nsc.interpreter._
  import play.api._
  import play.api.Play.current 

  val settings: Settings = {
    lazy val urls = java.lang.Thread.currentThread.getContextClassLoader match {
      case cl: java.net.URLClassLoader => cl.getURLs.toList
      case _ => sys.error("classloader is not a URLClassLoader")
    }

    lazy val classpath = urls map {_.toString}

    val tmp = new Settings()
    tmp.bootclasspath.value = classpath.distinct mkString java.io.File.pathSeparator
    tmp
  }

  val imain = new IMain(settings)

  def run(code: String, returnId: String) = {
    this.imain.beQuietDuring {
      this.imain.interpret(code)
    }
    val ret = this.imain.valueOfTerm(returnId)
    this.imain.reset()
    ret
  }
}
```

Useful links I found to make this second implementation:

- [scala.tools.nsc.IMain within Play 2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16511233/scala-tools-nsc-imain-within-play-2-1)
- [How to set up classpath for the Scala interpreter in a managed environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6839830/how-to-set-up-classpath-for-the-scala-interpreter-in-a-managed-environment)
- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scala-user/wV86VwnKaVk
- https://github.com/gourlaysama/play-repl-example/blob/master/app/REPL.scala#L18
- https://gist.github.com/mslinn/7205854

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because `play` uses the "fork in run" feature from `sbt`. This feature starts a new JVM and this causes that this failure appears:

```
[info] Failed to initialize compiler: object scala.runtime in compiler mirror not found.
[info] ** Note that as of 2.8 scala does not assume use of the java classpath.
[info] ** For the old behavior pass -usejavacp to scala, or if using a Settings
[info] ** object programatically, settings.usejavacp.value = true.
```

See: http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Forking

Answer (score 1):

After spending a few hours on this issue myself, here is a solution that I came up with. It works both inside SBT and outside. It is also expected to work in a variety of managed environments (like OSGi):

```
private def getClasspathUrls(classLoader: ClassLoader, acc: List[URL]): List[URL] = {
    classLoader match {
      case null                        => acc
      case cl: java.net.URLClassLoader => getClasspathUrls(classLoader.getParent, acc ++ cl.getURLs.toList)
      case c                           => LOGGER.error("classloader is not a URLClassLoader and will be skipped. ClassLoader type that was skipped is " + c.getClass)
                                          getClasspathUrls(classLoader.getParent, acc)
    }
}
val classpathUrls = getClasspathUrls(this.getClass.getClassLoader, List())
val classpathElements = classpathUrls map {url => url.toURI.getPath}
val classpath = classpathElements mkString java.io.File.pathSeparator
val settings = new Settings
settings.bootclasspath.value = classpath
val imain = new IMain(settings)
// use imain to interpret code. It should be able to access all your application classes as well as dependent libraries.
```